# how to combine SSD with tracker to accomplish multiple object tracking

Tags: tracking, object-detection

how to  combine object detection algorithm (e.g. SSD, YOLO, Faster RCNN and so on) with tracker(e.g. KCF TLD and so on) to accomplish multiple object tracking? Somebody could share concerned papers, blogs, wedsite or github code??  thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You only need a single combination of detection and tracking such as Yolo-KCF or SSD-KCF to track multiple objects.

You can use Darknet Yolo for detection:
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet

and SORT for tracking:
https://github.com/abewley/sort

or combined:
https://github.com/Qidian213/deep_sort_yolov3

you can try the different combination with same rules.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to do object detection via the mentioned object detection architecture like YOLO, SSD and so on and pass those results to a tracker for object detection over multiple frames.

A simple introduction is here to find: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/06/tracking-multiple-objects-with-opencv/